# Re-fetch data from server.ts and rebuild components when having multiple routes going to the same [Dynamic_route] in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

i have a Routing structure which is saved in a DB, i create the links like that:

```
{#each nav as navPoint}
    <a href={navPoint.path}">{navPoint.title}</a>
{/each}
```

The *only* route i have in the project is `[dynamic_routes]` with the files +page.svelte and the +page.server.ts.

In the server file i get the data i need based on the URL the nav-point gives me which works totally fine.
The content is builded in different components, those are rendered like this

```
{#each content as content}
    <svelte:component this={components[content.componentName]} {...content} />
{/each}
```

My problem is, that if i click on the different nav-points nothing happens if there already was a first load of the page (the components do not re-render and the server fetch does not happen). This only works on complete page refreshes.

**Is there a way to trigger a re-fetch and rebuild of the components every time the URL changes?**

Thank you.